# JqChart - How to display two graphs on the same page?

Tags: jquery, charts, jqchart

How to display two graphs on the same page?

I tried to put a column chart next to a line graph, and using the variables with different names within functions, the two graphs are in conflict. Displays no error in firebug, but the graphics are 'crazy'.

http://www.jqchart.com

Comment: I'd check to make sure the elements you're graphing to aren't using the same `id`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have different id-s. You can add 2 div containters with different names and make them charts with $('#selector'):

```
...
$('#jqChart1').jqChart({...});
$('#jqChart2').jqChart({...});
... 
<div id="jqChart1" style="width: 400px; height: 250px;">
</div>
<div id="jqChart2" style="width: 400px; height: 250px;">
</div>
...
```

You can check this sample as well:
http://www.jqchart.com/samples/FinancialCharts/StockChartWithVolume

It has 2 charts on the page.

Comment: The problem was with a variable that was being used in two functions, which caused conflict. It was lack of attention. Thank you.